# Give me error validator in undefinded but I used global key in Flutter, how to debug this error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

> Undefined named parameter error occurred when I used validator function in form text Field

I used the Global key and want to validate my form text field but when using the validator function compiler show the error validator is undefined. My code in a Flutter as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreen();
}

class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
  //GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //child: Text('This is bakwas container'),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          //validator:(){},
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .7,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const TextField(
                  // validator: (value) {
                    //   if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    //     return 'Please enter some text';
                    //   }
                    //   return null;
                    // },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email', hintText: 'abc@example.com'),
                  ),
                  //const SizedBox(height: 10,)
                  const TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Press IT')))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `validator` you need to replace `TextFiled` with [`TextFormField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Email', hintText: 'abc@example.com'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TextField your validation should look like below

```
class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
 final _userEmailController = TextEditingController();
 void errorDialog(String title, String msg) {
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text(
      title,
      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    content: Text(
      msg,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        child: const Text('OK'),
      )
    ],
  ),
 );
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Test"),),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      TextField(
        controller: _userEmailController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'asdf@gmail.com',
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_userEmailController.text.isEmpty) {
            errorDialog('Message', 'User email can not be empty!');
          }
        },
        child: const Text(
          'Login',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```